# NodeJS http-proxy module returning SSL error when connecting to certain doamins

Tags: node.js, ssl, http-proxy

I am using the node js HTTP-Proxy module to proxy requests to domain. When I use the module to proxy requests as below I get an SSL error

```
 httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    fs = require('fs');
    process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0;

    httpProxy.createServer({
      ssl: {
        key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem', 'utf8')
      },
      target: 'https://company.com',
      secure:false
       // Depends on your needs, could be false.
    }).listen(443);
```

This error out

Error: write EPROTO 4548494784:error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 80

However when I try to get to the same domain using Request module I get a proper response

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => request({
  uri: 'https://company.com'
}).pipe(res))
```

This works fine.

This error is only noticed in SSL connection to some domains. I suspect its something in the domain. However I cant understand how Request module could work and the http-proxy module will fail for the same url considering they would be probably be using the same underlying foundation code. If someone can help throw light on where I am going wrong, it would be much appreciated.